# Qual a diferença de /bin/bash e /usr/bin/env bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Não tenho muito conhecimento de script shell, sempre usei `/bin/bash`, todavia notei outras variações:

1. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
2. `#!/usr/bin/bash`
3. `#!/bin/bash`

Qual a diferença entre elas?

Até aonde li isso é devido a portabilidade entre diferentes sistemas (ou *kernels*), gostaria de saber como chamar declarar o tipo do script de maneira que funcione em sistemas unix-like, como sistemas baseados em **Linux**, **Mac OS X** e sistemas baseados em **BSD**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, o `#!` em um *shell script* é conhecido como *shebang* ou *hashbang*. Ele tem o formato de um *comment* (linhas iniciadas com `#` normalmente são ignoradas pelo shell), mas o `!` logo em seguida serve para indicar qual é o executável que vai processar aquele script.

Quando você diz:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

ou

```
#!/bin/bash
```

está chamando o executável `bash` para interpretar seu script. Poderia ser o python ou outro interpretador.

O problema é que de *distro* para *distro*, o lugar do `bash` (ou do `python`, por exemplo) pode ser diferente. Quando você faz assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

está executando o comando `env` com o parâmetro `bash`. O env serve para criar um ambiente novo, e o parâmetro a seguir é o comando que será executado pelo `env` neste ambiente.

Como o `env` usa o *path* do sistema, o `bash` será executado sem que você tenha que definir seu caminho exato.

Este artigo resume bem isto (en):

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/finding-bash-perl-python-portably-using-env.html

Agora, resta saber se é realmente verdade que o `env` vai estar sempre em `/usr/bin` :)