# O que é exatamente uma CLI?

Tags: terminologia

Pelo que já percebi, existem diversas CLI's. Exemplo:

- Ionic CLI
- Angular CLI
- Cordova CLI

Mas o que é exatamente uma CLI? É possível usar esses *frameworks* sem o uso dessas CLI's?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CLI que significa *command-line interface* (interface de linha de comando), ele é resumidamente uma interface que suporta passagem de parâmetros via linha de comando em terminais e/ou semelhantes.

Em outras palavras, é um programa que aceita parâmetros para executar comandos ou até mesmo inicia um próprio sistema de *I/O* (*input* e *output*) no terminal, sem que finalize o programa.

Note que em sistemas Unix-like o programa não precisa ser de fato um executável, ele pode ser um script que tenha no cabeçalho um programa *"interpretador"* e assim isto poderá funcionar em CLI (globalmente ou não), um exemplo que usa o `/bin/bash` crie um script chamado `foo`:

> **Nota:** `/bin/bash` é a localização do executável bash, esta localização pode variar de sistema para sistema [Qual a diferença de /bin/bash e /usr/bin/env bash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143822/3635)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Seu comando:" $1
```

Então execute:

```
./foo teste
```

Irá exibir na tela:

> seu comando teste

Até mesmo com PHP é possível, crie um script e chame de `baz`:

> **Nota:** `/usr/bin/php-cgi` é a localização do executável php-cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi
<?php
echo 'Seu comando:', $argv[1];
```

Então execute:

```
./baz teste
```

Já em Windows apenas executáveis com a extensão `.exe` ou scripts `.bat`, `.vbs` (entre alguns outros formatos de script que com o tempo irei enumerar aqui) podem ser executados.

---

> É possível usar esses frameworks sem o uso dessas CLI's?

É provável que você consiga criar um projeto ou baixar um projeto sem suas interfaces CLI, mas devo dizer, nas versões atuais, criar um projeto ou iniciar um "servidor" ionic (comando `ionic serve`) por exemplo é tão trabalhoso que mal compensa o trabalho, pesquisei bastante sobre os três (angular, ionic e cordova) e não vi nenhuma maneira menos que difícil de usar qualquer um deles sem suas próprias CLIs.

Creio que mesmo que fossem frameworks independentes de seus CLI e fossem fáceis de trabalhar, ainda sim com CLI sempre seria mais fácil, já que para criar um projeto basta um comando.