# Como surgiu a CLI (command-line interface) e qual foi essa necessidade?

Tags: terminologia, console, cli

Se olharmos para até uns 10 anos atrás, não lembro de termos esse recurso para o desenvolvimento de aplicações através do CLI (command line interface) nos sistemas operacionais Windows.

Exemplos utilizados hoje:

*Ionic CLI, Angular CLI, Cordova CLI*

Comment: Vou dar minha opinião, sem embasamento.
Acredito que a necessidade foi facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor. Se pegarmos estes 3 exemplos que você sitou. Imagina a quantidade tempo que seria desperdiçado para criar a estrutura inicial de um projeto com o angular. 
Ter de criar todos os arquivos padrões na mão, importar todos os pacotes necessários,  etc.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é exatamente uma CLI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242032/91)

Comment: legal. mas a minha pergunta é bem diferente.  o pessoal hoje usa muito do CLI. estou entrando nesse mundo, porém não consegui achar nenhuma referencia que mencione o surgimento dessa ampla utilização do CLI. sei que sempre tivemos linha de comando no windows, um exemplo é o DOS, que inclusive comecei aprendendo lá em 95.

Comment: A meu ver não chega a ser uma "ampla utilização da CLI". Cordova e Ionic são interligados, havia a CLI do Cordova, penso que foi natural surgir alguma coisa para Ionic. Adicionar Angular aí não chega a caracterizar uma ampla utilização. E antes desses existia o _git bash_, conta? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sempre teve, só que era tão natural que ninguém falava muito disso.

Um dos motivos é o aumento na complexidade de gerencialmente dessas ferramentas. E as pessoas tendem ser mais produtivas usando uma entrada de dados simples. Uma GUI, ou WUI pode ser útil para melhorar a descoberta de recursos, mas não é mais produtivo. Por isso que eu sempre digo que é comum que as UIs atuais estejam erradas e são improdutivas. É possível ser produtivo com GUI se souber muito o que está fazendo, em Web UI é bem mais difícil.

Mas a grande vantagem é poder automatizar a execução de certas tarefas quando se tem isso, ainda que eu ache que uma API mais direta fosse uma solução melhor. Inclusive em cultura DevOps se torna obrigatório.

Então surgiu da necessidade, como tudo em TI. É só uma questão de entender se será a melhor solução para o problema, ou uma nova variável na equação que pode tornar o problema mais complexo.

No sentido geral nem dá pra fazer como surgiu porque tem décadas, muitas.

Não imagino o que o Windows tenha a ver com isso. Linux e outros sistemas operacionais tem funcionalidades iguais, ou pelo menos assemelhadas. Se está dizendo que o Windows não tem linha de comando, tem antes até de ser Windows, sempre teve.

É claro que tudo isso pode ser feito via GUI ou outra forma, mas não permite a mesma flexibilidade ou praticidade.

Particularmente, apesar de achar bom, acho que a simplificação de algumas coisas traria um resultado tão efetivo que uma CLI nem seria tão necessária.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).